# SQL statement to to find where items are of a type, contain a status, and are the most recent addition

Tags: sql, sql-server

This should be simple but I can't figure this one out. I need to get a row of data that where a field in that row is the max value of that column and a particular status has been set on that row filtered down by a value.

This is an example of the table:

```
ID          Date Entered        Item       Status 
1           1/1/2012            Joe        Ready
2           1/2/2012            Joe        Ready
3           1/1/2012            Sam        Ready
4           1/2/2012            Sam        Not Ready
5           1/2/2012            Sam        Ready
6           1/1/2013            Jimmy      Not Ready
```

The result set that I want to get back is:

```
ID          Date Entered        Item       Status
2           1/2/2012            Joe        Ready
5           1/2/2012            Sam        Ready
```

This is one of my many failed attempts thus far:

```
Select id, max(Date_Entered), Item
from table1
where status = 'Ready'
Group by Item, id
```

This returns too many items with duplicates

```
Select max(Date_Entered), RELEASE_GROUP_C
from table1
where status = 'Ready'
Group by item
```

This doesn't return the ID.

Comment: What database server?  Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL?

Comment: I am using SQL-Server for my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this:

```
SELECT ID, [Date Entered], Item, Status
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY [Date Entered] DESC)'RowRank'
      FROM Table1
      WHERE Status = 'Ready'
      )sub
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8a8b/1/0)

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row starting at 1 for each grouping defined in the `PARTITION BY` section and the order based on the `ORDER BY` section, in this case, for each `Item` it will start numbering at 1 for the newest/latest date.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
SELECT ID, Date_Entered, Item, Status 
FROM t1 
WHERE 
Status = 'Ready'
AND 
t1.Date_Entered = (SELECT MAX(Date_Entered) FROM t1)
```

Comment: I'm assuming he doesn't just want the max date of all rows and just wants the max date per item group as Goat CO said with the windowing function below. This is just an assumption because the OP wasn't clear

Answer (score 0):

```
with CTE_TEMP as 
(
    select
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by Item order by Date desc, ID desc) as row_num
    from temp
    where Status = 'Ready'
)
select *
from CTE_TEMP
where row_num = 1
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8466/6)